# Why isn't \ddots working while \vdots works?

Tags: errors, amsmath

I have the following matrix

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}(p) & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}(p) & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n}(p) \\
 \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1}(p) & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}(p) & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_n}(p) \\
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ \\
 \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_1}(p) & \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_2}(p) & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n}(p) \\

\end{bmatrix}$$
```

which complies nicely. However, in the third line of the matrix, I would like to change the third "\vdots" to a "\ddots". If I do so, I get the following error:

> LaTex Warning: No \author given.
>
> (The directory on my computer)
>
> !Missing $ inserted.
>
> < inserted text >
>
> $
>
> I.72 $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots
>
> $ & $\vdots$ \
>
> ?

Could anybody help please?

Comment: It only "compiles nicely" if you ignore the error messages. Everything between `$$…$$` is already in math mode, so you don't need more `$...$` around the `\vdots`

Comment: @marmot LOL fixed it

Comment: @alephzero Ah thanks got it; unfortunately I am using TexWorks and when it complies it does not open the window with the error messages, so I was not aware I had any.

Comment: You might want to replace `$$ ... $$` by `\[ .. \]`, add a documentclass, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: @marmot I have the begin/end document and document class; I just wanted to show the packages I was using in case it affected the answer. That's interesting, I didn't know that \\[ could replace $$. I am used to the latter from math.stackexchange. Is there any benefit to using the former?

Comment: @Ovi Yes, there is, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/121799). And people benefit *much* more from compilable code than from fragments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curiously enough, `\vdots` is also legal in text mode, because it is defined as

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\vdots}{%
  \vbox{%
    \baselineskip4\p@ \lineskiplimit\z@
    \kern6\p@\hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}%
  }%
}
```

This fact should *not* be exploited, better use `\vdots` only in math mode.

On the contrary, `\ddots` is surrounded by `\mathinner`, so it has to appear in math mode:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ddots}{%
  \mathinner{%
    \mkern1mu
    \raise7\p@\vbox{\kern7\p@\hbox{.}}%
    \mkern2mu
    \raise4\p@\hbox{.}%
    \mkern2mu
    \raise\p@\hbox{.}
    \mkern1mu
  }%
}
```

What happens with your input can be understood once you realize that `bmatrix` internally uses `array`, where each cell implicitly has `$` at the beginning and `$` at the end. Thus in

```
 $\vdots$
```

the first `$` exits from math mode, producing an empty formula; then `\vdots` is typeset in text mode and finally another empty formula is produced from the trailing `$` and the implicit `$` at the end.

With `$\ddots$` it is the same, but now TeX finds `\mathinner` in text mode and raises an error.

How to cure this? Just don't use `$` inside `bmatrix` or anything that's already in math mode.

*Caveat 1*. I've seen several pieces of MathJax code where `$` seems to be used as a mean to produce “weird” symbols: something like `$\alpha$ = $\beta$` or worse. The code should be `$\alpha=\beta$`, of course.

*Caveat 2*. ***Never*** use `$$` in a LaTeX document. See [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

You may also want to increase the vertical spacing between the first two rows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
M=\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}(p) &
  \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}(p) &
  \cdots &
  \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n}(p) \\[1.5ex]
  \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1}(p) &
  \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}(p) &
  \cdots &
  \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_n}(p) \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_1}(p) &
  \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_2}(p) &
  \cdots &
  \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n}(p)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Curious indeed: perhaps the LaTeX team should consider a correction to the implementation of `\vdots`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough response! I was also wondering how to make my entries further apart in the matrix and I got it now

Answer (score 4):

Once you use [`\[`...`\]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764), you're in display math mode and therefore don't need to supply in-line `$`...`$` around math content:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
  M = \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}(p) & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}(p) & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n}(p) \\
    \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1}(p) & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}(p) & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_n}(p) \\
                 \vdots                  &              \vdots                  & \ddots &              \vdots                  \\
    \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_1}(p) & \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_2}(p) & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n}(p)
  \end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```